# Test of statistical hypotheses for parameters exercise

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing, distributions, mathematical-statistics

The exercise is the following:

Let X1,X2,..,Xn a random sample from a distribution with density function

$f(x; θ) = θx^{θ-1} \;\;\;\;\;\;for\; 0 < x < 1\; where\; θ > 0$

The null hypothesis $H_0 : θ = 1$ is to be rejected in favor of the alternative $H_a : θ >1$ if and only if at least 5 of the sample observations are larger than 0.7. What is the significant level of the test?

I know the significant level is $α = P(H_0 \; is\; rejected | \;H_0 \;true)$

And $H_0$ is true with θ = 1.

The problem is that I don't know how to transform the "at least 5 of the sample observations are larger than 0.7" into a function. I tried to sum the observations, but it didn't work. In addition, the result must be α = 0.0109, but it has no sense for me, because we know that θ = 1,  then the function become $x^{1-1} = 1$, then it is not always greater than 1 for each distribution int the random sample?

Comment: You are right that when $\theta = 1$, the probability _density_ function $f(x) = 1$ for all $0<x<1$. But that is not the probability of $X_i$ greater or smaller than a certain value.

Comment: With that said, does the question mention anything about $n$? I might be wrong but the significance level might depend on $n$?

Comment: @B.Liu Oh yes sorry n is 6, I have a random sample of size 6.

Comment: Now the question makes more sense. Continuing to comment to provide hints as per the community's policy on [exercises](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info): 1) Given when $\theta=1$, $f(x) = 1$ for all $0<x<1$ (which hopefully it should resemble some standard distribution), can you find the probability that _one_ sample is greater than 0.7? 2) With the answer to the above, can you find the probability that _at least five out of six_ samples (i.e. 5 or 6) are greater than 0.7?